# can't store data from response of aws rekognition

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, metadata, boto3, amazon-rekognition

I need to store and print data from the response from ResponseMetadata of AWS rekognition but I had an error. I write the code with python.

Error:

```
  File "example_eguest_search_V6.py", line 32, in <module>
  data = match['HTTPHeaders']['date']
  TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Code:

```
 import boto3

 import io
 from PIL import Image

 rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='eu-west-1')
 dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1')

 image = Image.open("sample.jpeg")
 stream = io.BytesIO()
 image.save(stream,format="JPEG")
 image_binary = stream.getvalue()


 response = rekognition.search_faces_by_image(
    CollectionId='test_Colction',
    Image={'Bytes':image_binary}
    )
 print(response)


 for match in response['ResponseMetadata']:
     data = match['HTTPHeaders']['date']

    print(data)
```

The response of AWS Rekognition:

> ```py
>     {u'SearchedFaceBoundingBox': {u'Width': 0.4403832256793976, u'Top': 0.3041895925998688, u'Left': 0.22959817945957184, u'Height': 0.3375910222530365}, u'SearchedFaceConfidence': 99.99995422363281, u'FaceMatches': [{u'Face': {u'BoundingBox': {u'Width': 0.27068600058555603, u'Top': 0.2908029854297638, u'Left': 0.3772050142288208, u'Height': 0.3391779959201813}, u'FaceId': u'965d9272-c16b-4055-ab3c-02e70d5a59af', u'Confidence': 100.0, u'ImageId': u'7397f3a2-f38c-38f9-8f96-4a059aa56635'}, u'Similarity': 99.8473892211914}, {u'Face': {u'BoundingBox': {u'Width': 0.3872449994087219, u'Top': 0.3262610137462616, u'Left': 0.279092013835907, u'Height': 0.40818700194358826}, u'FaceId': u'384e2cdd-e0f5-4768-8365-aa01369b8394', u'Confidence': 100.0, u'ImageId': u'c0239570-285b-3ac0-9614-be6f2ec872c1'}, u'Similarity': 94.60191345214844}, {u'Face': {u'BoundingBox': {u'Width': 0.38614898920059204, u'Top': 0.4011250138282776, u'Left': 0.5023319721221924, u'Height': 0.4669739902019501}, u'FaceId': u'08f5570f-bd57-48ee-bc3e-8ae6bd7dfd66', u'Confidence': 99.9999008178711, u'ImageId': u'996a26ce-d9dc-3f9d-bb0d-d61b78ad4422'}, u'Similarity': 94.2291488647461}], u'FaceModelVersion': u'4.0', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'b0b35916-9db9-45db-810d-45b19153d4de', 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Sun, 27 Oct 2019 14:36:14 GMT', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'b0b35916-9db9-45db-810d-45b19153d4de', 'content-length': '1071', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'connection': 'keep-alive'}}}
> ```

Comment: "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str" that's your error, use intergers instead of strings for de indices, data = match[1][1] for example

Answer (score 0):

The devil is likely in the details:

> CollectionId='test_Colction',

should be with an 'e' in collection:

> CollectionId='test_Colection',

For the rest see the example that you tried to mirror:

```py
# file: test-5-search-faces.py 

import boto3

BUCKET = "amazon-rekognition"
KEY = "search.jpg"
COLLECTION = "my-collection-id"

def search_faces_by_image(bucket, key, collection_id, threshold=80, region="eu-west-1"):
    rekognition = boto3.client("rekognition", region)
    response = rekognition.search_faces_by_image(
        Image={
            "S3Object": {
                "Bucket": bucket,
                "Name": key,
            }
        },
        CollectionId=collection_id,
        FaceMatchThreshold=threshold,
    )
    return response['FaceMatches']

for record in search_faces_by_image(BUCKET, KEY, COLLECTION):
    face = record['Face']
    print "Matched Face ({}%)".format(record['Similarity'])
    print "  FaceId : {}".format(face['FaceId'])
    print "  ImageId : {}".format(face['ExternalImageId'])
```

Posted code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/alexcasalboni/0f21a1889f09760f8981b643326730ff) at github. Its author is user alexcasalboni.

Comment: the name of collection of rekognition i created is  test_Colction not test_Colection

Comment: We call that a "typo". See other code I've posted. Try to use defs to keep oversight and enable to reuse it later in another method.